# Linking libraries statically

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

I have to write a programm that should afterwards run on a supercomputer, so I got the hint I should link my libraries statically.

The problem is when I link

```
g++ -o calcrank -llinbox -lgivaro -lgmp -lntl -static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc calcrank.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llinbox
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgivaro
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lntl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Of course, all the libraries I used I have only available as *.so libraries instead of static *.a libraries. Is there a convenient way to convert the *.so libraries or any suggestions on how to proceed to get a self-conatined running program?

Comment: To get the `*.a` libraries you need to compile them, or have them compiles already. I don't see how could it be possible to convert from dynamic libraries to static ones

Comment: Meanwhile I just installed gmp-static via yum, so one problem less. But unfortunately I think this is not so easy for the other ones.

Comment: That's a step haha
Why do you think you can't use dynamically linked libraries ? I never heard about supercomputers being annoying on that

Comment: The shared library contains the same objects as the static library, but they are already linked to each other; I suppose that unlinking them (converting addresses back into symbolic references) is possible, but I know no easy way to do it.

Comment: Actually I am at this point because this was suggested after another question of my side on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321592/use-supercomputer-to-run-a-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no easy ways, as far as I know.

There are some tools for "static linking" shared libraries:

1. [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net) (open-source)
2. [Ermine](http://magicermine.com) (closed-source, paid)

You should probably ask about this, maybe you can bring shared libraries along and set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your shared libraries directory in a script before running your program.

As far as I remember Statifier didn't work for me. Ermine unlicensed gives some warnings and a 30-day limitation message, probably. So to distribute my thing across Linux systems with no admin rights I collected [all needed shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124588/633969) into a subdirectory, made a script that sets the env variable and launches my executable. And distributed it all as a zip.

Comment: I tried to use statifier but then I get the error "ElfClass '64' do not supported on this system." I am working on a 64 bit OS so why does this error appear?