# How to calculate text, rodata, data and bss sizes of one module in C?

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

In my project, I first compile `aa_1.c`, `aa_2.c`... from folder `A`, then compile `bb_1.c` `bb_2.c`... from folder `B`. Then I use `gcc-ar` to generate `libapps.a`. At last, I link with other static libraries.

Now I want to calculate `text`, `rodata`, `data` and `bss` section of folder `A`.

My method is to execute `gcc-nm -S --size-sort folder/*.o`, and accumulate `text`, `rodata`, `data` and `bss` sections. But some functions may be optimized away because they're never called.

So how can I calculate `text`, `data`, `rodata` and `bss` sizes?

I also have another question, using `gcc-nm -S --size-sort a.o` there is no `'b'` type. But using `gcc-size a.o` shows `bss` section is 8 bytes. So which one is right?

Comment: Have a look at `readelf -S`. It will report the address for each of the sections that you can use to calculate the size.

Comment: `But some functions may be optimized away because they're never called.` - you only know that _after_ you do the final link when creating the executable. Ergo, such calculation has to be done after the executable is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Get list of static libraries used in an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124571/get-list-of-static-libraries-used-in-an-executable), the library names are discarded during the linking process.

You can add `-Xlinker -Map=file.map` to the link command, and then try to extract information from the 'file.map'.